# bootstrap on very low resolution

Tags: bootstrap-4, display

I have been using Bootstrap for several years and now I have to develop a webpage for a 640x480 (480p) display screen.
The strange thing that I noticed is that the grid layout of Bootstrap doesn't work with this resolution.
Despite setting the correct "col-", each element of the page is placed on a different line.
Why is this happening?
Maybe Bootstrap has a minimum width-size?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid ?

Comment: @sonal.paghdal how can I do that if i have only the bootstrap css and js file